# Inconsistencies in the values of energy gaps

Tags: superconductivity

I began to study the literature on superconductivity and discovered a very strange fact that I could not explain for myself:

1) The BCS theory establishes the fact that the energy gap is proportional to the critical temperature:

$2\Delta(0)=3.53 k_BT_c $

(In some experimental articles, there were $5-7$ instead of $3.53$)
However, it can be noted that the equation is satisfied only when the gap is tens of meV. (Even if we take into consideration a superconductor with a critical temperature of 100K.)

2) The book states that the gap for YBCO is greater than 1 eV. (Screenshot attached)

3) I also came across an article where the energy gap of LaCuO was about 2 eV:
https://authors.library.caltech.edu/96740/

Accordingly, I have a question: can the expression for the gap be used for high-temperature superconductors? (In a number of experimental articles it is confirmed.)

I understand that BCS does not explain high-temperature superconductivity, however, formula 1) is often used in experimental  articles on high-temperature superconductivity as confirmation of the correctness of the results.

Please tell me where I could be wrong.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The gap equation is a direct consequence of the BSC theory (weak coupling). It is modified at strong coupling regimes (Eliashberg theory - see Park's excellent book on superconductivity), and the consistency of non-BCS superconductors with it usually considered accidental, if nothing about the underlying mechanism is known.

Comment: @Alexander Please consider converting that comment into an answer.